# How to install Aforge image processing lab on Linux with Wine

Tags: linux, centos, wine

I am trying to install Aforge Image Processing Lab on my Centos.

I configured my wine to 32bits like;

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winecfg
```

And I install .NET 2.0 framework like;

```
env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet20
```

And also I install .exe file on `~/.wine32/drive_c/Program\ Files/` directory

Up to now, everything is quite good for me. However when I start;

```
wine iplab.exe
```

It gives me such error and it doesn't start;

```
[mg@MgCentOS bin]$ wine iplab.exe 
fixme:ntdll:find_reg_tz_info Can't find matching timezone information in the registry for bias -120, std (d/m/y): 8/11/2015, dlt (d/m/y): 29/03/2015

Unhandled Exception:
System.NotSupportedException: Can't get timezone name.
  at System.CurrentSystemTimeZone..ctor (Int64 lnow) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.TimeZone.get_CurrentTimeZone () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.DateTime.get_Now () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox+ComboTextBox..ctor (System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox owner) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox/ComboTextBox:.ctor (System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)
  at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_DropDownStyle (ComboBoxStyle value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox:.ctor ()
  at IPLab.HistogramWindow.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IPLab.HistogramWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) IPLab.HistogramWindow:.ctor ()
  at IPLab.MainForm..ctor (AutoOpenMode autoOpenMode, System.String autoOpenParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) IPLab.MainForm:.ctor (IPLab.MainForm/AutoOpenMode,string)
  at IPLab.MainForm.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotSupportedException: Can't get timezone name.
  at System.CurrentSystemTimeZone..ctor (Int64 lnow) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.TimeZone.get_CurrentTimeZone () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.DateTime.get_Now () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox+ComboTextBox..ctor (System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox owner) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox/ComboTextBox:.ctor (System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)
  at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_DropDownStyle (ComboBoxStyle value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox:.ctor ()
  at IPLab.HistogramWindow.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IPLab.HistogramWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) IPLab.HistogramWindow:.ctor ()
  at IPLab.MainForm..ctor (AutoOpenMode autoOpenMode, System.String autoOpenParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) IPLab.MainForm:.ctor (IPLab.MainForm/AutoOpenMode,string)
  at IPLab.MainForm.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IPLab.MainForm.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mg@MgCentOS bin]$
```

Could you please help me how I can handle this error and start Image Processing Lab application?

Answer (score 0):

`PlayOnLinux` is a nice graphical frontend for `wine` that (for me at least) is much easier to operate.

As a test I installed Image Processing Lab 2.8.0 using the `PlayOnLinux` "Install a non-listed program" feature.  The program installed perfectly and worked on the first try; I loaded and tweaked a few images and things seem to work well.  I tested with `PlayOnLinux` version 4.2.9, the current version.

If you don't have PlayOnLinux, you can get the RPM at http://rpm.playonlinux.com/ or other versions at https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html.

At the main screen, choose `Install`, then `Install a non-listed program` option in the bottom corner.